# How did we first discover oxygen exists as $\rm O_2$ and not just $\rm O$?

Tags: experimental-physics, physical-chemistry, history, molecules

How did we first discover oxygen exists as $\rm O_2$ and not just $\rm O$ ? (similarly hydrogen as $\rm H_2$ and not $\rm H$)

I vaguely remember knowing a story about how the chemical formula of *water* can be calculated.

This is quick. Doing electrolysis, we see two kinds of gases. One gas occupies twice the volume of the other gas. Assuming any gas occupying the same volume contains the same number of molecules, we conclude that the chemical formula of water is $\rm H_2O$.

[image]

Suppose hydrogen exists as $H$ and oxygen exists as $O$. To reverse above experiment, we can think of taking $1L$ oxygen and $2L$ hydrogen :
$$O+2H\rightarrow H_2O $$
I don't see anything wrong with above equation and electrolysis seem to confirm above equation, so I'm tempted to conclude that hydrogen exists as $H$ and oxygen as $O$. What am I missing ?

Comment: Nice question but is it [chemistry.se] rather than physics?

Comment: @badjohn I agree this is more of chemistry, but I'm doing thermodynamics at the moment and I feel physicists know this better than more chemists :)

Comment: If you are asking about the behaviour of gasses then this is the right place but for $O_2$ v $O$, I think that you would be more likely to get an answer in chemistry.  I think that at one time, it was assumed the compounds had their elements in equal quantities hence HO.

Comment: I think that would be my first guess too if I didn't have tools like Electrolysis and the Avogadro law. I do want to know about $O_2$ v $O$. I think I'll wait a bit more and shift this to chemistry if nobody answers. Thank you for responding! @badjohn

Comment: I'll watch out in both places.  It is interesting to speculate on how the experiment would be interpreted without modern knowledge.  That water is made of hydrogen and oxygen but hydrogen has twice the volume per atom?  Would we know atoms?  Maybe water is fundamental and the products are combinations of it with whatever comes out of of the two terminals of the battery.

Comment: Totally agree history of these is indeed fascinating, and I remember knowing the answer to this before. I don't seem to recall it... Since  Volume is a *macro* variable, we may be okay even if we don't know the diameter of  individual atoms. Avogadro's law says that *any* gas will have the same number of molecules at a given volume, right ? (keeping pressure and temperature fixed)

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong. Avogadro's law says something like this :  

$1L$ of *any* gas contains the same number of molecules if they are at the same pressure and temperature.

Comment: Did we know that before we knew the composition of water?

Comment: Ohhk.. I see the error. I've been assuming that water has hydrogen and oxygen.   I think we can do this :  Take $1ml$ water and convert it entirely into gases using electrolysis. Then we will have known the composition - two atoms of one kind and one atom of another kind. Did I get this right ?

Comment: Well you know the real answer.  What makes this thought experiment a little hard is how much you knew before?  Did you already know that water was a compound of hydrogen and oxygen?  Did you understand electricity?

Comment: We have that question, even though it doesn't really have the *best* answers: [How was the diatomic nature of many common gaseous elements originally determined?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/22270/4945) Also related: [How were the first molecular formulas determined?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/15386/4945)